# Which investigations against Trump are getting delayed due to the government shutdown? (if any)

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, government-shutdown, trump-wall

There are currently several investigations on-going that involve Trump.  Many of them are listed here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_investigations_into_Trump_and_Russia_(2017)

So my question is: does extending the partial government shutdown delay the processing of any of the investigations surrounding Trump?  And if so, which ones?

Comment: "Several of my friends tell me" - People spread gossip all the time. You may want to look into the controversial election of Donald Trump. Because Trump's election was controversial, people were upset because they feared for their lives. So, it's entirely possible that people would start negative rumors about Trump.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't help answer the question.  The purpose of this post is to figure out if the rumor is true.

Comment: @DoubleU I have updated the question to make the intent more clear.  If you down-voted the question, please help me understand how I can improve its quality.

Comment: The downvote was not from me.

Comment: "Which criminal investigations against Trump" - This question is still problematic. Read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Trump_sexual_misconduct_allegations

Comment: The "criminal investigations" can be anything, including the sexual misconduct allegations.

Comment: That is correct, they can be.  So is the question not specific enough?

Comment: @David I edited the question to focus it on what you're actually asking for, rather than the reasons. If you don't agree, you can roll it back.

Comment: Yes. It is too broad.

Comment: @DoubleU why is it too broad? Either no investigations are put on hold due to the shutdown or one or more of them are.

Comment: The sexual misconduct allegations may turn into criminal investigations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

Law enforcement officers are considered essential employees and are still working during the partial government shutdown, even without pay. Federal courts are still handling criminal cases, and are expected to handle them uninterrupted after funding runs out on January 25. The Special Counsel's investigation is and will continue operating. Congress is still able to investigate whatever it wishes.

Comment: Thanks, this appears to be correct.  I also found this article, which says that 84% of the Justice Department is not impacted by the government shutdown:  https://www.rollcall.com/news/politics/shutdown-effects-breakdown-department-agency